# Communication between main program and sub modules

Tags: architecture, mef

I am planning to uses the MEF framework in order to  be extensible.  My program 3 sub modules/dlls as given below

Messenger module - to send/receive messages across the network, includes a thread.
A shell extension module .
A database module.

The main module decides how and when to delegates task to the sub modules. Right now i am planning to use and events and callback to communicate back to main module from a sub module.

I need to know what is the best, resource efficent way to communicate between main and sub modules. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) service found in Microsoft's Prism library. I can't guarantee it is the most resource efficient method, but this service was created specifically to help you communicate in modular applications. [Here is a nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample) you can look at.